# Codeigniter file upload error: You did not select a file to upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is really odd, I tried to check the top suggestions in google that is similar to my issue here but I believe those are not the answers to this. I'm using the default 'userfile'.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

The structure of my form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('register','role="studentForm" class="form-horizontal'); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userfile" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Profile Picture</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" id="userfile">
        </div>
    </div>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-login-style btn-sm pull-right">Submit</button>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

The structure of my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){

        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']             = 2048;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->upload->initialize($config); 



        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){

            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());

            echo $error['error'];
        }else{

            $uploaded_pic = $this->upload->data();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

NOTE: 'Upload' library is loaded automatically in autoload.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok  i got it. I am missing a quotation `"` in my class:

the wrong code:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('register','role="studentForm" class="form-horizontal'); ?>
```

the correction here:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('register','role="studentForm" class="form-horizontal"'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing `$this->upload->do_upload();` before the if else statement? 
don't need to specify twice.

Comment: ah yeah, that one. using my code above it shows two sentences 'You did not select a file to upload'. If i remove that, i still get same error but with one sentence though.

Comment: not sure if this is the right one, but you missed out a comma on this line, between role and class 
<br/>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('register','role="studentForm" class="form-horizontal'); ?>

Comment: and can you also try to use this instead? 

<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'studentForm'); 
echo form_open_multipart('register', $attributes); ?

Comment: i just followed the instruction here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_open#form_open under adding attributes. I guess that will not matter? but i will try and update you about it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have called `$this->upload->do_upload();` twice. Pls remove the first one.

And use `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');` in place of `$this->upload->do_upload();`

Comment: i still get same error, as what i said in the previous answer.  It only shows two error messages, i removed it. And now still showing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The Second Line in Your View,Please Correct it

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('register','role="studentForm" class="form-horizontal" '); ?>
```